# PHPExcel skipping Excel lines

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have used PHPExcel just a little but am finding that it seems to skip some lines when reading in an Excel spreadsheet. I have a file with 11857 lines and it seems like only 11814 were read - well that many were processed for writing to a database. I don't get any errors when my program runs. I wrote a second program to read the Excel again and to look for each line in the database....of the 48 lines that were missing, the second check program found 25. I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this so I get all records? It seems to also happen on a file with about 4,000 lines in it (I thought it might have been due to size). I only want certain fields, so I find their column position by reading the first row, then go through the rest of the file and write those fields in a database (unless it is already in there). Some of the input does not have an Id so I look for the name if no ID provided. My code is below:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setReadFilter( new MyReadFilter() );
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); 
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); 


$colHeaderArray = array();
$numberHeaderArray = array();

for ($row = 1; $row <= 1; ++$row) {
    for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
        $rows[$col] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
        $colHeaderArray[] = $rows[$col];
        $numberHeaderArray[] = "field".str_pad($col+1, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }

    $partId = array_search('PartnerId', $rows);
    $partName = array_search('PartnerName', $rows);
    $status = array_search('status', $rows);
    $city = array_search('city', $rows);
    array_pop($colHeaderArray);
    array_pop($numberHeaderArray);
}

$dataRows = array();

for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
    $myDataArray = array();
    $dataRows[0] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($partId, $row)->getValue();
    $dataRows[1] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($partName, $row)->getValue();
    $dataRows[2] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($status, $row)->getValue();
    $dataRows[3] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($city, $row)->getValue();
    $myDataArray[]= $dataRows;
    addPartner($dataRows);
    array_pop($myDataArray);
}

function addPartner($row) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
    $err = '';

    if ($row[0] == '') {
    //echo "empty ID";
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM partners WHERE partnerName = '".$row[1]."' ");
        $err = "name already in";
    } else {
        //echo "not empty ID";
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM partners WHERE partnerId = '".$row[0]."' ");
        $err = "number already in";
    }

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO partnererror (id, name, comment) VALUES ('".$row[0]."', '".$row[1]."', '".$err."')");
        return;
    } else {
        $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO partners (partnerId, partnerName, status, city) VALUES ('".$row[0]."', '".$row[1]."', '".$row[2]."', '".$row[3]."' )");       
    }
}
```

Comment: So what debugging have you put in place to see where the rows are being lost? Whether in `for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {` or somewhere in `addPartner($row)`?

Comment: None yet. Wasn't sure if I am using the functions for the reader the right way or if there was a better way to go through the sheet.  This is my first experience with PHPExcel and I was using it the way someone else was (which could be wrong)

Comment: Well there's no obvious problems with the way you're looping through the rows reading the data; though your `$objReader->setReadFilter( new MyReadFilter() );` could be setting the loader to ignore certain rows

Comment: sorry, forgot to include that:

    class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
{
 public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
  if ( $row >= 0 ) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }
}

Comment: Don't bother with the read filter at all then, it serves no purpose other than adding a degree of performance overhead to the loader

Comment: But I'd be inclined to put some debug in place to check the values that you're reading from each row

Comment: ok, I will try. It would help to be able to check for the exception since with 11,800 records checking each one to see if it's there may be difficult. i guess i almost need to write to the database and then check to see if it was added and if not, then write it out somewhere. So, I can get rid of the filter it seems (from your comment).

Comment: If you don't use a filter, then it will read every cell; the purpose of a filter is to limit the cells you read, but your filter is limiting that to every cell anyway (row > 0), with the extra overhead of that check

Comment: thanks. maybe it's slowing it up enough to cause a skip....I think I'll try doing without it first and see what happens. can't hurt i guess. thank you again.

Comment: Slowing things down won't cause a "skip"

Comment: oh true...sorry was thinking before it was going to fast. but you're right...one would think if it processed a little slower it shouldn't skip.

Comment: Mark - I may have found something. I was trying to see if there was a pattern in the records count or records that were skipped and noticed that most, if not all (I didn't go through all of them), of the ones skipped in my file have a 'city' column that starts with an ' (an apostrophe). I do set the charset to utf8, but I am thinking that maybe the INSERT into the table is not working because of the apostrophe....so probably not a PHPExcel issue but a SQL issue....

Comment: An apostrophe in a SQL statement would certainly cause problems if it wasn't escaped

Comment: I did a find all in my Excel for ' and came up with I think the same number of rows that I am missing. So now....how to escape it when I don't know what's in there.....at least closer to finding a solution. thanks.

Comment: You could always use `trim()` to remove leading or trailing quotes; or a str_replace() to remove quotes completely (though there are valid city names containing apostrophes like O'Fallon, IL or Coeur d'Alene, ID), or use your database interface to escape the quotes

Answer (score 0):

I made a little function to return a properly escaped string back....before my INSERT, I call this function for the two fields that could potentially have an apostrophe in them. Then use the returned strings for the INSERT. I reran my loading program and now ALL records are being uploaded. Thank you for your help!

```
function cleanString($input){
   $mysqli = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);    
   $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
   $output = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $input);
   return $output;
}
```